# Subscribe to security event log error

Tags: c#, window

Is there a way to subscribe to Security event logs ?

This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202.aspx

explains about how we can subscribe to Application event logs but when I try the same for Security event log, **I get Unauthorized access error**.

I have modified the manifest file to use the "requireAdministrator" and "highestAvailable" and auditing on SecPol.msc.but none works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig deeper into the registry... esp. `MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security\CustomSD,1,%SecCustomSD%,2`

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323076/en-us